# How to get rid of \n in the variable when using subproces lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm running a bash command through Python to get the stdout.

This is the start of the command

```
bashCommand = "kubectl --context mlf-eks-dev get --all-namespaces ingressroutes"
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I then try to remove the `\n` from the output

```
output = process.communicate()[0].decode('ascii')
```

When doing a print, no issue.

```
wwwvhugo                        wwwvhugo-mlfwordpress                                          134d
```

Yet when I'm only running `output`, I still see the `\n`

```
wwvhugo                        wwwvhugo-mlfwordpress                                          134d\n'
```

I tried to use the `strip()` but I do not think it is related.

Thank you.

**Note**: There are no whitespaces at the start or at the end of the string.

Comment: Hi @BradSolomon, I did not do the split. Lemme try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
bashCommand = "kubectl --context mlf-eks-dev get --all-namespaces ingressroutes"
output = subprocess.check_output(bashCommand.split(), text=True)
output = " ".join(output.splitlines())
```

However, after many tryout, using a regex can help too (like below)

```
import re
output = subprocess.check_output(bashCmdNamespace.split(), text=True)
output = re.sub('\s+',' ',output)
```

Comment: Hi @BradSolomon, updated my question. Cheers mate.